# Finding the Javascript file from browser

Tags: javascript, debugging, backbone.js, browser, web-applications

I have the code base of a web application(based on backbone.js).When i get bug reports in form of screenshots/steps, I would try to reproduce the specified bug . Once I have done reproducing the bug.

a)how can I find the JavaScript file responsible for the logic behind the UI, quickly from the browser itself or in a less time consuming way?

b)Is there a efficient technique to find the right JS file?

In order to fix the logic..

Browser used:  Chromium/Google chrome

Comment: Learn about your browser's dev tools & debugger.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: thanks guys.. it was helpful